# Tomcat 8 - ClassNotFoundException: FilterConfig

Tags: java, tomcat, azure-active-directory

Im on OSX (10.12.6).  I've cloned and built this java code sample for authenticating with Azure AD:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/resources/samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect/

I've moved the packaged `adal4jsample.war` into my Tomcat installation at:

`/Users/Shared/resources/apache-tomcat-8.0.38/webapps`

My Java version is "1.8.0_102"

When I start Tomcat, the error log shows:

> 02-Dec-2017 22:00:04.582 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
>    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/adal4jsample]]
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: FilterConfig
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:273)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationFilterAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:64)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:336)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:786)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>       ... 10 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FilterConfig
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
>       ... 24 more

A search shows that FilterConfig exists in Tomcats included libs at:
`/Users/Shared/resources/apache-tomcat-8.0.38/lib/servlet-api.jar`

Any suggestions what to try or check next?

EDIT: I've just tried exactly the same steps on a different Mac with same OSX version, so there's definitely some problem in my environment on this one.  Not sure how to determine what the problem is though..

Comment: maybe your installation is corrupt. Have you tried on a fresh tomcat installation?

Comment: yes, I've tried with totally new installations of Tomcat 8.0.38 and 8.5.24

Comment: FilterConfig also exists in portlet-api, in another package, but looking at the git repository of that code it is referring to servlet-api so that's not the problem either... peculiar.